# Passphrase generator script

Tags: security, random, bash, linux

Below script is used to generate passphrases for gpg (or anything really).

Do you see any blatant security mistakes in it?

I wrote it by myself, because I couldn't find any passphrase generator that doesn't use external services and uses /dev/urandom.

Note: I run it with `./generator.bash 4 > x && vim x` so stdout is not printed to the terminal, but I'm not sure if this is neccessary. I'm thinking that somewhere terminal history could be stored.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./passphrase_gen.bash 4 > x && vim x
# We redirect to file and print via vim so no history is saved anywhere.
# Repeat after you get passphrase you like. Memorize it/write it down
# and remove x afterwards.
set -eo pipefail

words=/usr/share/dict/words

# https://serverfault.com/a/214620/216850
sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom

n=$1

# print $n randomly chosen words from $words file
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
  # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268960
  random=$(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom)

  lines=$(cat $words | wc -l)

  line=$((random % lines))
  awk "NR==$line" $words
done
```

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/jan-swiecki/9974501047c79bad12a3c87cfe846cd6

Comment: You could usefully read the [Diceware homepage](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) which has a lot of advice about generating passphrases, as well as some useful (and large) wordlists.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: I run it with `./generator.bash 4 > x && vim x` so stdout is not printed to the terminal, but I'm not sure if this is neccessary. I'm thinking that somewhere terminal history could be stored.

I don't think this is necessary.
If anything, you might forget to remove `x`,
which could be a security risk.

#### Avoid `seq`

`seq` is not a standard tool, and a native alternative exists:

```
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do ...; done
```

#### Extract constants out of loops

This statement is executed in each iteration of the loop:

> ```
> lines=$(cat $words | wc -l)
> ```

But the content of the `$words` file is likely constant,
so it's safe to compute this once, before entering the loop.

#### Unnecessary `cat`

The `cat` command is unnecessary with `wc`, it's better to redirect input:

> ```
> lines=$(wc -l < "$words")
> ```

#### Double-quote variables in command line arguments

Although the content of `$words` doesn't contain spaces,
as a good practice it's good to double-quote it when using as program arguments, for example instead of:

> ```
> awk "NR==$line" $words
> ```

Write:

```
awk "NR==$line" "$words"
```

#### Arithmetic context

Instead of this:

> ```
> line=$((random % lines))
> ```

You can write simpler:

```
((line = random % lines))
```